# Paypal After payment not return to website show 404 error

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment-gateway, express-checkout

For my Magento website Version 2.2.2 I am using `Paypal express checkout` but from few days I am facing the issue customers makes the payment at moment it doesn’t return back to website instead it shows a 404 error and because of this no email is sent to customer, admin and also order doesn’t show in admin sales page.

Cancel URL is working as expected. Its redirect to cart page.

Can anyone help me on this solution?

Comment: check what are you passing in `return_url`, also auto return must be enable from paypal account

Comment: As I know express checkout not required to set the return URL in paypal. While sending the request it set all the parameter like success, failed URL etc. BTW return URL is OFF in Paypal account.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR let me correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR I am sending the returnURL like  'RETURNURL' => 'https://domainname/paypal/express/return/' in the request. Should I enable the return must from paypal account.